# Chrome quick list open specific website

Tags: google-chrome, quicklists

I have managed to get quick list showing for chrome, however I would like to add a link which opens chrome and goes to a certain website. How can this be achieved?

```
   X-Ayatana-Desktop-Shortcuts=NewWindow;Incognito;

[NewWindow Shortcut Group]
Name=New Window
Exec=google-chrome
TargetEnvironment=Unity

[Incognito Shortcut Group]
Name=New incognito window
Exec=google-chrome --incognito
TargetEnvironment=Unity
```

Comment: can you add your current quicklist to the question?

Comment: added, sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have access to an Ubuntu machine right now, so I can't try this. But can you pass a website as an argument to the google-chrome command?

I'm testing this on Windows 7 and it works. Calling

`chrome www.google.com`

from the command line opens Chrome and loads google.com. I'm pretty sure this is how Firefox on Ubuntu works as well.

So try editing (or adding) an entry in your quicklist with the line

`Exec=google-chrome www.website.com`

and see if that works.